# httr package, parsed response is missing NA values

Tags: r

I'm using the httr package to download some data from a server. Now the returned data works fine. Except that I'm requesting 500 lines (maximum set by server) at a time, and the NA values are not present in the returned data under my current setting.

My code

```
parsed.JSON   <-as.data.frame(content( GET(url.string), as = "parsed") )
```

Now with this, the parsed data may look like

**#1 Data1**
**#2 Data2**

When in reality, the data is #1 Data1 #2 NA #3 Data2, the NA values have simply been skipped over in the parsed version. How can this be fixed?

Comment: Can you give a the real URL, so that we can attempt to duplicate the problem

Comment: Thing is, it's an API call, so I'm afriad no.

Comment: What I meant is, what is the value associated with `url.string`

Comment: url.string is the api url call, however this url contains privatekey and username etc.

Comment: Did you try yet getting the raw result back via `content(..., as = "text")` then parsing manually?

Comment: Well, I tried to use the jsonlite package. With fromJSON(parsed.JSON), but the argument has to be a txt or file or url.

Comment: I've tried with another package (RJSONIO) and there also can't retrieve the NA values. Although I'm parsing manually. I suspect I'm missing a specific argument value.